# Lucky Day Hacker Earth Problem giving wrong answer

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, optimization, integer, complexity-theory

You are given an array of integers. An integer is said to be "lucky" if every integers after it are not greater than the selected one. You have to count the total no of Lucky integers present in the array and print it at the last.

I tried the simples O(n2) complexity for the solution but yet I was unable to pass 4 testcases which were unfortunately hidden. Can you guess what should be those testcases which bypass the given algorithm  below or if you have any better solution please let me know.

```
**for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
       flag=true;
   for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++){
       if(a[j]>a[i]){
           flag=false;break;
       }
   }
   if(flag)
     count++;
}**
```

Please note that the count=1; initially because the last element in the array is by default lucky integer.

Example:
Input: [2,4,5,1,1]
Output:  3

Comment: There is a O(n) solution. Did you get a wrong answer, or a time limit issue?

Comment: One braking case is the empty array, it seems's not to be ruled out

Comment: Probable `O(n)` approach would be to traverse from last element which will always be lucky. Once you find lucky number, increment the `count` and remember that lucky element. Now you just need to compare if `k-i` th element is `greater` than just previously found lucky number. If it is then again increment the count and remember the lucky number found for further use.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that yout problem lies in the complexity. A complexity O(n^2) is generally too much in this kind of problem.

A number is lucky if it is greater than all remaining numbers, i.e. greater than the maximum value of these remaining numbers.

This maximum value can be calculated iteratively.

Complexity: O(n)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int lucky (const std::vector<int> &A) {
    int n = A.size();
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    int count = 1;
    int vmax = A[n-1];
    for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (A[i] >= vmax) {
            count++;
            vmax = A[i];
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A= {2,4,5,1,1};
    int count = lucky(A);
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```